# Receiving an unclear error when using SelectMany() on an IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq

When I write the following code I get the error:

> the type argument for method Enumerable.SelectMany cannot be inferred from usage

```
var model = new Overview()
{
   ModelData = data.GroupBy(g => g.GroupingId1).Select(s => new OverviewdataGrouped()
   {
       Id = s.Key,
       Grouping = s.GroupBy(gr => gr.GroupingId2). Select(se => new OverviewdataGroupedFurther()
       {
           Id= se.Key,
           Grouping2 = se.Any() ? se.SelectMany(sel => sel).ToList() : new List<DataModel>()
       })
   })
};
```

As far as I know this is how I always selected the data from an `IGrouping`, but for some reason it is not working this way. Does anyone know what I am missing or what the problem could be?

(Note that the variable sel within the `SelectMany` contains the correct type (DataModel))

Comment: Please, share the rest of code and reproducible sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SelectMany Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Your usage of the SelectMany method seems redundant, since `se` is the result of a grouping operation. Try replacing this:

> se.SelectMany(sel => sel).ToList()

By This:

> se.ToList()